# Access Denied error with OpenEncryptedFileRaw function

Tags: c++, windows, file, encrypting-file-system

I am trying to open a efs encrypted file using [OpenEncryptedFileRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openencryptedfilerawa). According to the documentation, the process should have SeBackupPrivilege for opening a encrypted file.
From process explorer I can confirm that the process has the necessary privileges for this operation, but still I see access denied error when trying to open the Encrypted file.I am also running both command line and visual studio as administrator.

Code Snippet:

```
PVOID context;
DWORD ret = OpenEncryptedFileRaw(fileName,0,&context);
```

One more thing I noticed was, even though I specify the fileName to be a name that doesn't exist I still get access denied error.
Do let me know if I am missing any basic setting or configurations.

Comment: It is not enough merely to have the privilege. You must also enable it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--

Comment: It is enabled. Will add a screenshot to the question